# Java EE TCP Socket Programming

Tags: jakarta-ee, jca

I've written a Java SE Application that uses `java.net.*;` for Socket Programming for transaction management and remote command line management.

I'd like to port the functionality to Java EE (for a number of reasons) - I've been told that in order to achieve this I will have to create a Resource Adapter to access a Socket - is there any way to manage TCP/IP sockets in Java EE without reinventing the wheel?

I've been programming in Java SE since 1999 but I have only recently started touching Java EE.